# why the function in different swift class not getting called?

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, swift3, uiviewcontroller

New to this just not getting what's going on for some reason there is no error or anything both the upper and lower print statements are executed, while the print in next class function is not executed ???

```
class LoginController: UIViewController{

var blankController:ViewController?


func handleLogin(){
    if let loginVCobj = self.containerCustom.currentViewController as? LoginClass
    {
        guard let loginEmail = loginVCobj.LoginName.text else{
            print("No Login Name to submit")
            return
        }
        guard let loginPassword = loginVCobj.LoginPassword.text else {
            print("No Login Password to submit")
            return
        }

        Auth.auth().signIn(withEmail: loginEmail, password: loginPassword){ (user, error) in
            if error != nil{
                print(error)
                return
            }
            print("user Logged in") <---- its printed 

      ///// updated to initialize ////
       self.blankController = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", 
   bundle:nil).instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: 
   "SWBlankRevealVCStoryBoard") as? ViewController


            self.blankController?.customNavigationBar() *-----NO PRINT
            print("Passed the BlankController") .  <---- its printed 
            self.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)

        }      

    }

   }
}
```

Now a different Class named ViewController

```
class ViewController: UITableViewController{

func customNavigationBar(){
     //something about the customizing the Nav Bar

    print("stupid call")
}

}
```

[image]

Comment: Did you already initialize the `blankController` variable? as far as I can see, you haven't yet which is why the function isn't being called.

Comment: Because you aren't really creating an object of ViewController?

Comment: @ElTomato how can i do that ?

Comment: Is `ViewController` inside a `Storyboard`, `Nib`, or a hard coded `class`? These three may have different initializers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`self.blankController?.customNavigationBar() *-----NO PRINT` in this line your `self.blankController` may be nil, as you have not initialise your view controller.

To ensure your view controller is initialised or not, prior to use it (its properties) try following

(Replace your print line `self.blankController?.customNavigationBar()` with following):

```
print("self.blankController = \(self.blankController)")  
// it may print self.blankController = nil
```

or

```
if let viewcontroller = self.blankController {
   viewcontroller.customNavigationBar()
} else {
   print("blankController may be nil")
}
```

There are several ways to initialise your view controllers (depending upon interface builder file of your view controller).

**Using Storyboard:** If your interface builder is located inside storyboard

```
blankController = UIStoryboard(name: "<Storyboard Name/String>", bundle: nil).instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("<view controller identifier>") as! ViewController

// Note: Do not forget to set identifier of your view controller, otherwise this will result into app crash. You've extended your ViewController with UITableViewController, so ensure implementation of all necessary datasource and delegate in your ViewController.
```

Here is reference image, help you, how to find/set identifier of view controller,

[image]

//----------------

**Update**

Cause of problem is your `ViewController` is extended by `UITableViewController` in you code.

```
class ViewController: UITableViewController
```

But in your story board, the same is class belongs to `SWRevealViewController....`, which is not a `UITableViewController`.

**Solution**

```
class ViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate {


    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
      // return number of row
    }


    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell{
      // return  UITableViewCell
    }
}
```

Comment: yea that was a stupid nil !!Thanks. New to this, how can i resolve this ?

Comment: Thanks again for the brief description but for some reason still end up in getting nil!!

Comment: BBooks70[62630:7900364] Unknown class _TtC8BBooks7022SWRevealViewController in Interface Builder file.
Could not cast value of type 'UIViewController' (0x11266b368) to 'BBooks70.ViewController' (0x10e9412e8).

Comment: the link is added at the end of the question

Comment: appreciate the effort it ain't working still, but when i tried adding a new view controller it worked, however this is what i am trying to do https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45550074/how-to-create-a-view-controller-that-has-menu-when-a-user-logs-in